# Stereo-mix is not working again after windows 10 update

Tags: audio-recording

I am not able to record sound from internet once again, probably due to windows updates. I have had trouble with stereomix before but that was simply fixed by enabling stereomix. This time I cannot get it working. I have an Aspire E5-575G with Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362).

What I have done so far:

Enable stereomix

I cannot make it the default driver (grayed out and not available in the popup menu). In all my tinkering I once was able to make it default, but that did not help.

Downloaded audio driver from Acer website for my model and installed it.

In the device manager I find:
Sound, video and game controllers: Realtek 6.0.1.8158 (the one I downloaded from Acer)
Audio inputs and outputs/Stereo-mix: Realtek 10.0.18362.1 
This I different so I tried to change this by using update driver and browse to the downloaded driver (6.0.1.8158), but it says "The best driver for your device are already installed"

If I use "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer" it needs an inf file but there are lots of them. It automatically picks the first one HDX861A.inf. That leads to an error "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems."

I updated the driver for Sound, video and game controllers (since that did not help I installed the one from Acer again)

I used System File Checker
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth 
sfc /scannow 
No problems were found

The Realtek HD audio manager interface does not show advanced settings, so I can't use that

I installed Vcable, but that also doesn't solve the problem

I am out of options, so your suggestions are more than welcome!